# How can I recovered history cell in Google Sheet using script editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to recover the cell history in google sheet file after I restored to the previous version. Because after restoring to the previous version, the history cell is gone. But I know that the data is still in the file as I can see it through the version history it is just the history for each cell is not there.

I am trying to use the script editor (I asked through Quora and this is the gist of the code that they send, as the exact code include some errors) but there are no changes. Are there any possible way that I can do to recover the history of each cell?

According to Abraham Jay Ride, I can use script editor to show the previous history. Here is the [link](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-recover-the-cell-history-of-Google-sheet-I-previously-restored-the-previous-version-and-now-I-cant-see-the-cell-history/answer/Abraham-Jay-Ride?__filter__=all&__nsrc__=notif_page&__sncid__=39067944382&__snid3__=52350404104) for the post that I referencing previously

```
function Code() { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell(); 
  var cellHistory = cell.getA1Notation(); 
  var history = cell.getSheet().createDeveloperMetadataFinder().withKey("cellHistory").find(); 
  history.forEach(function(meta) { 
    if (meta.getValue() === cellHistory) { 
      var msg = "Cell history: " + meta.getDescription(); 
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(msg); 
    } 
  })
}
```

[the screenshot of the script editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9YyC.png)

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Where did you find this script?

Comment: I just edited the information so that it is easier to see. For the script, I previously asked in Quora and the person recommended for me to try using the script editor.

Comment: AFAICS, the code seems to be written by ChatGPT: It makes up stuff. I never knew that there was a `cellHistory` developer metdata associated with history. It is neither documented and based on experimentation, doesn't seem to be true either. Getting history is currently not possible with script: It is requested as a feature:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151809 Even if the feature is implemented, you're asking for previous version's cell history: I don't think that's possible. You may add a feature request in the  issue tracker.

Comment: I'd hate to add more rules on your first post, but we have strict rules on code attribution. As you [can see in referencing guidelines](/help/referencing), you should 1. Name the author, 2. Quote the code, and 3. Include a link to the original post